# Why is Django 1.0.x not able to install from PyPI?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pip, easy-install

I tried it on virtualenv:

```
(venv) $ pip install Django==1.0.4
Downloading/unpacking Django==1.0.4
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==1.0.4 (from versions: )
No distributions matching the version for Django==1.0.4
Storing complete log in /home/tokibito/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Looks as though the latest version is the only one available for download from pypi.

Comment: @hd1 - that's not true - see http://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/ for a list of versions available from PyPI.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, PyPI only has Django versions 1.1.4 and upwards. If you want the old version, you can just install directly from github:

> pip install git+https://github.com/django/django.git@1.0.4

Comment: +1, well done, I think you beat me by a couple seconds, and with a full command.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to use it.

Comment: To remember where i can install django :D

Answer (score 1):

You could always [point your requirement.txt](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html#git) directly at the version you want from the [official Github repository](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/install/#installing-development-version).  I've never done it this way, so I can't walk you through it, but it seems like a viable option if you *need* to run a specific version that's not on PyPI.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an alternative code source within your requirements.txt file.

```
#Django==1.0.4
git+https://github.com/django/django.git@1.0.4
```